# Pack a float to 1 byte using the reverse of provided unpacking function?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a function that unpacks a floating point value stored in a byte and turns it into a float.  The function looks like this:

```
private double unpack(byte count)
{
    byte xor = (byte)(count ^ 0xFF);

    ushort mantissa = (ushort)(xor & 0xF8);
    int exponent = xor & 0x07;

    if (xor == 0x08)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (exponent == 0)
    {
        return xor / 512.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((mantissa | 0x100) << (exponent - 1)) / 512.0;
    }
}
```

My questions is: How do I do the reverse of this?  I now want to take a float and turn it into a byte using the same method (but reversed).  I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to do this, so am coming here for help.

Comment: seems the byte contains an unsigned [minifloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat) with 5-bit mantissa and 3-bit exponent. The line `byte xor = (byte)(count ^ 0xFF);` can simply be replaced with `byte xor = (byte)~count;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in C (I do not know C#) with comments and a test program. The `Encode` routine should round to the nearest representable value, but the program only tests exactly representable values.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef uint16_t ushort;


//  This is the original decoding algorithm with comments inserted.
static double unpack(byte count)
{
    //  Complement the bits.  The purpose for this is unknown.
    byte xor = (byte)(count ^ 0xFF);

    //  Separate the significand encoding and the exponent encoding.
    ushort mantissa = (ushort)(xor & 0xF8);
    int exponent = xor & 0x07;

    /*  Special case:  0xf7 (0x08 after complement) represents zero.  This is
        strange, as there is another encoding (0xff) that represents zero.
    */
    if (xor == 0x08)
        return 0;

    //  If the exponent encoding is zero, the number is subnormal.
    else if (exponent == 0)
    {
        /*  In a subnormal number, the implicit bit of the significand is zero,
            and the exponent is the minimal value supported, so the number
            represented is merely the significand encoding scaled for the
            minimum exponent.
        */
        return xor / 512.0;
    }

    //  Otherwise, the number is normal.
    else
    {
        /*  In a normal number, the implicit bit of the significand is one.
            ORing with 0x100 adds this bit.

            Then we scale by the exponent.
        */
        return ((mantissa | 0x100) << (exponent - 1)) / 512.0;
    }
}


/*  Convert x to the encoding of the nearest representable value in the scheme
    above.  This routine requires IEEE 754 arithmetic.
*/
byte Encode(double x)
{
    /*  The encoding arbitrarily sets 0xf7 (0x08 after XOR) to represent zero.
        If not for this exception, 0xf7 would represent 8/512.  Because of it,
        the smallest positive value that can be encoded is 16/512.  In order to
        ensure that conversion rounds to the nearest representable value, we
        set a threshold midway between that and zero.  Numbers at or below the
        midpoint are rounded to zero.

        If not for this exception, Clip could be set to zero.
    */
    static const double Clip = 16./512 / 2;

    /*  Encode zero and negative numbers.

        The encoding appears to use both 0xf7 and 0xff to represent 0, and it
        is not clear which ought to be returned in any particular circumstance.
    */
    if (x <= Clip)
        return 0xff;

    /*  Encode subnormal numbers.  In a subnormal number, the significand is
        scaled by a fixed amount, and the exponent encoding is zero.
    */
    if (x < .5)
        return (byte) (round(64*x) * 8) ^ 0xff;

    /*  If the number exceeds the maximum representable value, return the
        maximum representable value.
    */
    if (63 < x)
        return 0;

    //  Encode normal numbers.

    /*  Use Dekker's algorithm to round the number to six significand bits.
        (The value 0x1p47 requires that the "double" type have 53 significand
        bits (53-47 = 6), as it does in the common IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary
        format.
    */
    double d = x * (0x1p47 + 1);
    x = d - (d - x);

    /*  Split the number into a fraction f in [1/2, 1) and a power of two e.
    */
    int e;
    double f = frexp(x, &e);

    //  Encode the exponent by adding a bias.
    e = e + 1;

    //  Remove the explicit leading 1 bit from the fraction.
    f -= .5;

    /*  Shift the fraction to the fraction field, insert the exponent encoding,
        and complement.
    */
    return ((byte) (512*f) | e) ^ 0xff;
}


int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 0x100; ++i)
    {
        double x = unpack(i);
        byte code = Encode(x);
        printf("0x%x -> 0x%x -> %.99g -> 0x%x.\n",
            i, i ^ 0xff, x, (unsigned) code);
        if (x != unpack(code))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bug found trying to encode %.99g.\n", x);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice work!  I'm currently wrapping my head around this and translating it to C#, but based on your full code including test, I have no doubt it will work.  I do have a question about 0x1p47.  This is something I'm not familiar with, and googling didn't turn up much of use.  Is there a name for this value that I could Google to learn more about it?

Comment: @user1930728: Search for “Veltkamp-Dekker split algorithm” for more information. `0x1p47` is a tunable parameter, not a fixed value; the power of two (47) is the number of bits to remove. Since there are 53 bits in a common `double`, removing 47 leaves six. By multiplying by `0x1p47 + 1`, the algorithm forces rounding to occur at a desired point in the arithmetic. This is needed only to round the input to the nearest representable value. If the input were known to be an exactly representable value, this step would not be needed. Explaining the details of why it works is for another question.

Comment: Thanks again for the information.  The keyword I was looking for on the 0x1p47 values was "hexadecimal floating point literal".  This was a new concept for me, but now makes sense.  Unfortunately, while these are a part of C++17, they are not it Visual Studio 2017.  That means I wasn't able to use this solution, but I'm still going to mark it as the answer, since it is a correct answer, and does a great job explaining the necessary steps.

Comment: @user1930827: You can generate 0x1p47 in other ways. It is just 2 to the power of 47. One sure way is `scalbn(1, 47)`. Hopefully the compiler would optimize that to a compile-time constant. But, if it does not, you can try 140737488355328 (or, since we are adding one, 140737488355329). But then I would want to make sure the compiler properly converts that without any rounding error. (Unfortunately, Microsoft does not have the best implementations of floating-point operations.)